# jQuery .hide() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I have a few span elements that I am hiding via CSS (display: none;).  When the page loads, I would like the first span element to show which in all browsers, except IE7, seems to be the case.  Anyone have any clue as to why this might be happening?  There isn't any crazy code that would cause this problem, it simply just isn't working.

jQuery v1.4.2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('span.player').hide();
        $('span.player:first').show();
    });
</script>

<span class="player" style="display: none;">Player embed code</span>
<span class="player" style="display: none;">Player embed code 2</span>
```

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: can you please share the code with us?

Comment: I've updated the question with the code.

Comment: That isn't. You edited it afterwards and plus you don't have it inside of a script element. Posting portions of that is not telling us the whole story which makes it frustrating to help.

Comment: If "player embed code" is an `<object>` or `<embed>` tag, it should not be in a SPAN, it needs to be in a block element like a `<p>` or `<div>` tag.

Comment: I replaced the span with divs and it still seems to not be working. :(

Comment: Jake - Is there some reason you won't post more of your actual code?

Comment: If you don't want to post your full code because it's 1000 lines or so, then just trim it down to the smallest possible code snippet which still reproduces the problem in your case and then post it here.

Comment: Check your html is correct (all tags opened are closed etc) also try changing the class name in case you've got cached css with !important which is overwriting the inline code

Answer (score 2):

The code properly hides the elements and shows the first, per your full code.

http://jsfiddle.net/LBjQD/5/

Answer (score 0):

If youve hidden these elements via a stylesheet and not via the style attribute on the element thats the issue.

Comment: I originally had the hidden attribute within the stylesheet but now the code is above and still not working :)

Answer (score 0):

Without showing us the full source code it is hard to know what your problem is, and we're left with having to take random guesses. From what I know the code is perfectly valid and the fact it works in other browsers means you probably included everything correctly. So this is a little confusing.

I would start by including a DOCTYPE if you haven't already. It is possible that IE is in quirks mode and that is rarely good.

Also, are you using prototype on the page as well as jQuery? This could be a $ conflict in which case you will need to call jquery in a non-conflicting way, like:

```
jQuery(document)....
```